# Django Inheriting from classes

Tags: python, django, inheritance

I have run into a problem developing my Django site.

```
from django.db import models

class TitlePost(models.Model):
    title_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    title_body = models.TextField(max_length=30000)
    title_why = models.TextField(max_length=250, null=True)
    title_publication_date = models.DateTimeField('date')
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dislikes = models.IntegerField(default=0)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title_name


class TopTitlesPostPage(models.Model):
    title_post = models.OneToOneField(TitlePost)
    hello = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.hello

class NewTitlesPostPage(models.Model):
    title_post = models.OneToOneField(TitlePost)
    hello = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.hello
```

Why don't `TopTitlesPostPage` and `NewTitlesPostPage` inherit all the attributes from `TitlePost`? For instance, if I try to call the `likes` in my template using `TopTitlesPostPage`, it will not execute because the `likes` attribute is not inherited. Does `OneToOneField` have something to do with the problem?  I did read that making `TitlePost` a meta class will help but I need it to have a table in my database.  I actually want all of them to have a table in my data base. Then again, maybe I am approaching this the wrong way and I should use just `TitlePost` as a model to generate everything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour you would like to see is called [multi table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance). Every child class internally ends up with the same thing that you wrote, so with a one to one field to the base class `TitlePost`, but it's internally managed by django.

If you do multiple inheritance like the code below you will be able to write:

```
k=TopTitlesPostPage.objects.create(hello="Hello",title_name="Heh")
```

That means the fields will be directly accessible.

```
from django.db import models

class TitlePost(models.Model):
    title_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    title_body = models.TextField(max_length=30000)
    title_why = models.TextField(max_length=250, null=True)
    title_publication_date = models.DateTimeField('date')
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dislikes = models.IntegerField(default=0)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title_name


class TopTitlesPostPage(TitlePost):
    hello = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.hello

class NewTitlesPostPage(TitlePost):
    hello = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.hello
```

In case you are never actually going to reference the base class `TitlePost`, but only its children it might be more appropriate to make `TitlePost [abstract](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes):

```
  class TitlePost(models.Model):
    title_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    title_body = models.TextField(max_length=30000)
    title_why = models.TextField(max_length=250, null=True)
    title_publication_date = models.DateTimeField('date')
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dislikes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title_name
```

Making `TitlePost`abstract will omit the creation of the table `TitlePost`in the database, and the child models will end up with the fields of the base class inserted into their own tables seperately. If the base class is just for factoring out common functionality this is the preferred way to go.

For huge queries this will also make a difference in performance because the ORM will need to do less `JOIN`operations.

It's not possible to install Foreign Keys to abstract models in Django.
You can however install Foreign Keys to a non abstract base class. The only limitation is that the reverse Foreign Key relation will return the base class instances.
You can circumvent this limitation by using [django-polymorphic](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Django Polymorphic allows you to query the base class objects but retrieves the child class instances:

```
>>> Project.objects.create(topic="Department Party")
>>> ArtProject.objects.create(topic="Painting with Tim", artist="T. Turner")
>>> ResearchProject.objects.create(topic="Swallow Aerodynamics", supervisor="Dr. Winter")

>>> Project.objects.all()
[ <Project:         id 1, topic "Department Party">,
  <ArtProject:      id 2, topic "Painting with Tim", artist "T. Turner">,
  <ResearchProject: id 3, topic "Swallow Aerodynamics", supervisor "Dr. Winter"> ]
```

To use django polymorphic you only need to declare your models with Polymorphic Model as base class:

```
from django.db import models
from polymorphic import PolymorphicModel

class ModelA(PolymorphicModel):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class ModelB(ModelA):
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class ModelC(ModelB):
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Foreign keys will also return the child class instances, which is really cool if you're trying to be polymorphic.

```
# The model holding the relation may be any kind of model, polymorphic or not
class RelatingModel(models.Model):
    many2many = models.ManyToManyField('ModelA')  # ManyToMany relation to a polymorphic model

>>> o=RelatingModel.objects.create()
>>> o.many2many.add(ModelA.objects.get(id=1))
>>> o.many2many.add(ModelB.objects.get(id=2))
>>> o.many2many.add(ModelC.objects.get(id=3))

>>> o.many2many.all()
[ <ModelA: id 1, field1 (CharField)>,
  <ModelB: id 2, field1 (CharField), field2 (CharField)>,
  <ModelC: id 3, field1 (CharField), field2 (CharField), field3 (CharField)> ]
```

Take into account that these queries will be [slightly less performant](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/performance.html).

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the info; this really helps a lot! I will definitely play around with this method!  So based on efficiency, I take it that making an Abstract class for everything is a better choice than taking the polymorphic route?  What would you chose between the two and why? If you don't mind answering.

Comment: When it comes to performance, never optimize prematurely. Generally you only want to take that into consideration when you have a database bottleneck. 
The polymorphic route enables you to do proper polymorphism, that means programming without if statements and takes full advantage of duck typing and is generally useful when you're building applications that should be extensible for the future. I'd use it for any project that's bigger than just a demo, but is not going to have tens of thousands of entries or hundreds of sub models.

Comment: Very interesting. I will definitely keep this in mind for future references. Thanks again for the info!

Answer (score 1):

U need to extend the classes like follows:

```
class TopTitlesPostPage(TitlePost):
```

U can add more and inherit from multiple models just by mentionin g all the models comma separated! This all the fields from the models will be created in the child class as well

EDIT:

The way i would do it is to create an Abstract class which contains all your common fields and extend it into your TitlePost, TopTitlesPostPagea and NewTitlesPostPage

Comment: Actually I tried that earlier and it didn't work for some reason. Maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: Did you define the TitlePost as abstract?

Comment: I did but since it was meta it wouldn't create table in the data base.  Then again, I didn't directly inherit like that from the base class after I made it a meta class, and instead used the relation `OneToOneField` provides.  I'll try this out!

Comment: Awesome, why didn't I think of that. That seems to be the best answer! Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `TopTitlesPostPage` and `NewTitlesPostPage` extend the base class of `TitlePost` like so ...

```
class TopTitlesPostPage(models.Model)
```

You don't need a `OneToOneField` if you are inheriting from the base class, since the attributes of `TitlePost` will be available to you in the subclass. If you want to make `TitlePost` abstract (you can not declare an instance of that class, only inherit from it) you have to add it to the meta class

```
class TitlePost(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Here is a link to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance).

Comment: Shouldn't `class TopTitlesPostPage(models.Model)` be `class TopTitlesPostPage(TitlePost)`?

Comment: @Stefan Bossbaly will the base class still create a table in the database even though it is a meta?